# Bottom detection javascript with overflow-x: hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website where I need to detect when at bottom of the page and then hide a div. My problem is that I also need to have the following css code:

```
.html,body {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

I am using the following javascript code for the detection:

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
  //Bottom Reached
  document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-arrow')[0].style.visibility='hidden';
  }
  else {
  document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-arrow')[0].style.visibility='visible';
  }});
</script>
```

This results in the javascript code being unable to detect when bottom is reached. Is it possible to bypass this and achiev what I want? PS. The javascript works perfectly when overflow-x is visible.

Comment: Aside from making the height of your document shorter, and overflow-x:hidden shouldn't do much else. What are your $(document).height() , $(window).height(), and $(window).scrollTop() values when you're at the bottom and it's not disappearing?

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle with a simple use case, and explain what is not working. Also, you are using jQuery *and* standard javascript. Why is this? Are you including jQuery properly?

Comment: If you got better stuff I can use please share it with me